# C : fopen_s() returns NULL if it works, so I cant close it with flose() and it also dont work togehter with fwrite()

Tags: c

Normally I would use `fopen` but with Visual Studio you have to use the secure variant `fopen_s`. But because `fopen_s` returns a `NULL` pointer if the action was successful, I cannot use the `fclose()` function to close the connection to the file. `fclose(filePointer)` is not possible because it is a NULL pointer. If I want to use functions like `fwrite()` or `fread()` that doesn't work either.

My Problem is when I use `fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str), filePointer)` -> "filePointer could be 0". Of cause its 0 because I get "0" if fopen_s(filePointer) works well.

Unfortunately, I can't find any examples of the security variants anywhere, because everyone uses the "normal" ones. I know that I can switch off the safety function, but I don't really want to do that, because safety is actually something good :D

Comment: [`fopen_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160) does not return `NULL` on success, but `errno_t` status `0`. The **address** of the file pointer is passed as an argment. It isn't like `fopen()`. You need `errno_t res = fopen_s(&filePointer, ...)` None of these "safer" functions are safe if you don't use them correctly.

Comment: There is another potential error with `fwrite(str, 1, sizeof(str), filePointer)` using `sizeof(str)`. This (depending on context) is either the size of a pointer, or the size of an array, and neither is likely to be right, when the choice of the variable name `str` implies a NUL terminated string, which may not be the whole array, and if it is, might not intend to include the NUL terminator.

Comment: "with Visual Studio you have to use the secure variant" simply isn't true. What you get is so many warnings (one for *every* occurrence) that they obscure other warnings and this is covered in the @paxdiablo answer too. Insert the line *before* any `#include` files. I also `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` and `#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example is right there on [Microsoft's doco page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=msvc-160) (abridged here):

```c
FILE *stream;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&stream, "crt_fopen_s.c", "r");
if (err == 0) {
    fclose(stream);
}
```

The first argument to `fopen_s` is a pointer to the variable that will receive the file handle, so it's *that* variable that you use to do whatever you need to do to the file (which is just closing it im my example above).

---

Note that these functions are *not* safe, though they may be safer than the originals. They check for specific `NULL` values but there are plenty of unsafe pointers that *aren't* `NULL`<sup>(a)</sup>.

It's always been my view that good code design makes these checks unnecessary, though I realise some may disagree<sup>(b)</sup>. Probably one of the *first* lines I put in my C programs is:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

so as not to have to put up with what *I* consider to be the Microsoft nanny state.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Such as `(void*)42`, for example.

<sup>(b)</sup> They are, of course, wrong.

Comment: UV for the additional remarks. A big danger of the supposedly safer versions is that users can think they are otherwise compatible. One such example is `scanf_s()` which isn't a drop-in replacement for `scanf()` but takes additional arguments when certain format specifiers are used.

Comment: There are multiple reasons for MS's purportedly "secure" alternative functions not having been widely accepted outside MS's own ecosystem, but among them is that in practice, they are not much safer or more secure.  You still need good code design and careful implementation to write safe code, and if you have those then indeed they are sufficient.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I concur. But, if you have "good code design and careful implementation", then `fopen()` is as safe as `fopen_s()`. If that's what you were actually *saying,* put it down to a mis-read on my part, I shouldn't be stackoverflowing when slightly drunk :-)

Comment: Thx for your fast asnwer. I put #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS into my first line, but if I use fopen without the _s the error "this functio or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s() instead" pop up. Did you know why?

Comment: Mb, I enter #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS under the #include's because it doesent worked.

Comment: @Erik, "Mb"? I'm guessing that's "my bad" as in "I made a mistake", but I just wanted to confirm. And yes, it should be before the includes since I believe it's the declaration of the function in the headers that marks it unsafe, the attempted use simply shows the warning for anything marked unsafe. Though I *could* be wrong, it's happened before, as my wife and spawns will attest to, frequently and without much prompting :-)